# Как измерить количество используемой методом памяти Python?

Tags: python

Есть метод:

```py
def method(g):
    x = []
    for i in range(g):
        x.append(i)
    return x
```

Нужно измерить количество потребляемой памяти.
Пытаюсь измерить с помощью `memory_profiler`, но его `PyCharm` почему-то не видит (***from memory_profiler import memory_usage*** написал).
Теперь вопрос, как получить именно используемую память?
Память вычисляется с помощью memory_profiler.memory_usage(), но почему-то не работает, если писать так:

```py
import memory_profiler


def method(g):
    x = []
    for i in range(g):
        x.append(i)
    return x


y = []
for j in range(len(10)):
    y.append(memory_profiler.memory_usage(method(10000)))
```

Comment: '''Теперь вопрос, как получить именно используемую память?''' запустите код на Jupyter Notebook и посмотрите memory usage.

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, потому что надо посчитать память для нескольких методов и потом составить соотношение на графике с помощью plt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу ответ, в вашем случае воспользоваться `memory_profiler` в venv.

Установить (macOS):

```sh
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -U memory_profiler
```

Установить (Windows):

```sh
py -m venv env
env/Scripts/activate
pip install -U memory_profiler
```

Первое, необходимо функцию саму задекорировать в `@profile`.

А затем вызывать ее в стандартной конструкции

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    method(10000)
```

То есть весь код будет выглядеть вот так:

```py
@profile
def method(g):
    x = []
    for i in range(g):
        x.append(i)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method(10000)
```

Теперь запусти на исполнение и посмотрим на результат

```sh
python3 -m memory_profiler func.py
```

Результат:

```
Filename: func.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     2   18.750 MiB   18.750 MiB           1   @profile
     3                                         def method(g):
     4   18.750 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       x = []
     5   19.203 MiB    0.266 MiB       10001       for i in range(g):
     6   19.203 MiB    0.188 MiB       10000           x.append(i)
     7   19.219 MiB    0.016 MiB           1       return x
```

Если же, вы хотите использовать в самом коде, то можно вот так

```py
def method(g):
    x = []
    for i in range(g):
        x.append(i)
    return x

from memory_profiler import memory_usage
print(memory_usage((method, (10000,))))
```

Результат:

```
[19.28125, 19.296875, 19.296875]
```

Все примеры использования взяты из [доументации](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)

Comment: а цпу профилера нет такого?

Comment: @eri вообще этот профилер наследует от `psutil`, там есть возможности cpu смотреть. Но вот прямо чтобы вот такой, не знаю)